# calling an event in main activity from other class?

Tags: android, events, onclicklistener

i am using page view in android and i view in this view an images. so i want to make event for on click. however, i call the image from another class like root view and i want the response of event  from main class `openoptionmenu()` so i is there any way to call the event from second class when click the image?

```
((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Object oo = ScreenSlideActivity.class;

            }
        });
```

Comment: how about starting new activity (Your SecondActivity), and do something in onStart/onNewIntent ...

Comment: the main class is activity but the second is a class

Answer (score 0):

Hi user3811293 I think you have 2 options, the first one pass Image view for call other time the event and the second one is create listener method in the other classes and call this. You can a simple sample here:

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/mobile-development/threads/483268/can-i-set-onclicklistener-to-another-class-android-java

I think this is that you want, if you need more help or same advice me, good luck!

Comment: hi merli my problem i have two class the first one is activity and the second is class

Comment: But this is no a problem! :O

Comment: i mean that it's different from the link

Comment: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/mobile-development/threads/488522/how-to-call-an-event-in-main-activity-fro-other-class